# Set ObjectName and then call it in a function

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm creating these labels using this in initUI(self):

```
for row in range(4):
    tmp = 0      
    for col in range(4):
        square = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        square.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap('img/tab.png'))
        #self.gridLayout.addWidget(square, row, col)
        #setattr(self, 'label_ligne_{}_{}'.format(row + 1, col + 1), square)
        label_name='label_ligne_{}_{}'.format(row + 1, col + 1)
        square.setObjectName(label_name)
        if row <1:
            test=300
        elif row <2:
            test=385
        elif row <3:
            test=470
        else:
            test =555
        square.move(300 + tmp, test)
        square.installEventFilter(self)
        print(square.objectName())
        tmp += 85
```

I'd like to acceses some of those labels in a function triggered by a button:

```
@pyqtSlot()
def on_click(self):
    print('PyQt5 button click')


def move_ligne_one(self):
    for btn in (
        self.label_ligne_1_1,
        self.label_ligne_1_2,
        self.label_ligne_1_3,
        self.label_ligne_1_4,
    ):
        if self.label_ligne_1_4.x() > 300:
            p = btn.pos()
            p -= QtCore.QPoint(85, 0)
            btn.move(p)
```

[image]

I need to move each row of labels individually by pressing the corresponding button. But I cant refer to the labels by using the name I'm assigning them

Comment: can you provide a minimal working example, so I can copy and try your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`findChildren()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#findChildren) and [`findChild()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#findChild):

> Returns all children of this object with the given name that can be cast to type T, or an empty list if there are no such objects.

Note that with PyQt there are [more overloads](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/api/qtcore/qobject.html#findChildren) of these methods, which slightly differ in their arguments, and you're probably interested in the first of those:

> findChild(type, name: str = '', options: Union[FindChildOptions, FindChildOption] = FindChildrenRecursively)
>
> findChildren(type, name: str = '', options: Union[FindChildOptions, FindChildOption] = FindChildrenRecursively)

```
def move_ligne_one(self):
    for btn in self.findChildren(QtWidgets.QLabel, QtCore.QRegExp(r'^label_ligne_1_[1-4]')):
        if self.findChild(QtWidgets.QLabel, 'label_ligne_1_4').x() > 300:
            p = btn.pos()
            p -= QtCore.QPoint(85, 0)
            btn.move(p)
```

Note that if you use `setattr`, you can access the widgets in a similar fashion by simply calling `getattr`:

```
def move_ligne_one(self):
    for btn in (
        getattr(self, 'label_ligne_1_1'),
        getattr(self, 'label_ligne_1_2'),
        getattr(self, 'label_ligne_1_3'),
        getattr(self, 'label_ligne_1_4'),
    ):
    # ...
```

Anyway, if you're going to have a fixed number of rows and columns, a simpler and better approach would be to create a "matrix" of your widgets:

```
    self.rows = []
    for row in range(4):
        rowItems = []
        self.rows.append(rowItems)
        for col in range(4):
            square = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
            rowItems.append(square)

def move_ligne_one(self):
    for btn in self.rows[0]:
        # ...
```

In this way you can access each item by their position, which is better than relying on object names or instance attributes.